# how to apply "Gather" operation like numpy in Caffe2?

Tags: operator-keyword, indices, caffe2

I am new to Caffe2, and I want to compose an operation like this:

- Numpy way

[example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOzky.png)

- pytoch way

[example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRPfV.png)

My question is, how to compose Caffe2 operators to make the same operators like above? I have tried some compositions but still I couldn't find the right one. If anyone knows the composition, please help, I will be really appreciate for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Gather operator in Caffe2. The main problem with this operator is that you can't set the axis (it's always 0). So, if we run this code:

```
model = ModelHelper(name="test")

s = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)
y = np.asarray([0, 1, 2])

workspace.FeedBlob('s', s.astype(np.float32))
workspace.FeedBlob('y', y.astype(np.int32))

model.net.Gather(['s', 'y'], ['out'])

workspace.RunNetOnce(model.net)

out = workspace.FetchBlob('out')
print(out)
```

We will get:

```
[[  0.   1.   2.   3.   4.]
 [  5.   6.   7.   8.   9.]
 [ 10.  11.  12.  13.  14.]]
```

One solution could be to reshape *s* to a 1D array and transform *y* in the same way. First of all, we have to implement an operator to transform *y*. In this case, we will use a numpy function called ravel_multi_index:

```
class RavelMultiIndexOp(object):
    def forward(self, inputs, outputs):
        blob_out = outputs[0]

        index = np.ravel_multi_index(inputs[0].data, inputs[1].shape)

        blob_out.reshape(index.shape)
        blob_out.data[...] = index
```

Now, we can reimplement our original code:

```
model = ModelHelper(name="test")

s = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)
y = np.asarray([[0, 1, 2],[0, 1, 2]])

workspace.FeedBlob('s', s.astype(np.float32))
workspace.FeedBlob('y', y.astype(np.int32))

model.net.Python(RavelMultiIndexOp().forward)(
    ['y', 's'], ['y'], name='RavelMultiIndex'
)
model.net.Reshape('s', ['s_reshaped', 's_old'], shape=(-1, 1))

model.net.Gather(['s_reshaped', 'y'], ['out'])

workspace.RunNetOnce(model.net)

out = workspace.FetchBlob('out')
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[  0.]
 [  6.]
 [ 12.]]
```

You may want to reshape it to (1, -1).

Comment: Thank you for your code, I think this is just what I needed. For caffe2's "Gather" operator, I tried it earlier, it is not what I wanted. And for your code, I think the use of "model.net.Python()” is really clever, I will run more tests on it. Thanks again.